# Reading an excel sheet with 500,000 records with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I have an excel sheet with half a  million records. The sheet has two columns one with telephone numbers and the other names of the number owner.

I want to read the numbers and submit them to a web service that sends bulk sms. I want to use laravel queue to process the worksheet.

Is it possible to read  the file faster and insert its contents in the database if i used multiple workers and how do i make sure workers do not re-read lines already read by other workers?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that [laravel-excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import#chunk) package has this feature (look at "Queued chunks" section).

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/46f1f9168202877d2d9c570042af315567b268c0/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Readers/LaravelExcelReader.php) confirm my suggestions, the `chunk` method creates *n* (number of rows divided by the chunk size) job requests where each job process part of the file. The only thing you have to do is to set up eq. redis queue driver and launch some workers using `php artisan queue:work` command.

Manual solution (which is hidden under above implementation):

1. Get number of rows in file without reading whole content,
2. Divide rows to *n* parts (number of rows divided by chunk size),
3. For each part create job request (you have to pass first and last row number which should be processed by this job). Each job should open the file, go to the specified starting row and read specified number of rows,
4. Launch some workers.